# Returning an agregated array by searching/comparing in an array of arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have 2 tables:

categories

```
id | name |  | slug   | path | parent_id  | depth
1    name1     slug1    {1}      null       0
2    name2     slug2    {1,2}      1        1
3    name3     slug3    {1,2,3}    2        2
5    nam5      slug5    {5}       null      0
......
9    nam4      slug9    {5,9}       5       1
```

where path is an `int[]array` type and works like a breadcrumb

items

```
   id | name
   1    name1
```

Between Item and Category there is a M2M relation

item_categories

```
 id | item_id  | category_id 
   1        1    |  3
   2        1       9
```

In the example above the Item is in 3 categories:

I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c1.slug, c1.parent_id FROM categories AS c1 
WHERE ARRAY[c1.id] <@ (SELECT c2.path FROM categories AS c2 WHERE c2.id= 
(SELECT category_id FROM item_categories WHERE item_id=8 LIMIT 1)) order by depth
```

to extract a breadcrumb base on path and it works.

But I want to get all breadcrumbs(not just one). Removing `LIMIT 1` and changing `= to in` I will have an array of arrays, instead of just an array, and will trigger an error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

which is normal.

Example of what I want - Item in:

```
cat1 - > cat2 - >cat3
ca5 -> cat9
```

, and from database(so I can loop over them):

```
[ [{'name':cat1, 'slug':slug1}, {'name':cat2, 'slug':slug2}, {'name':cat3, 'slug':slug3}], [{'name':cat5, 'slug':slug5}, {'name':cat9, 'slug':slug9}]]
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f756cfe568d38425dfe25cfec60b1b3f

So instead of obtaining one breadcrumb how can I get an array o breadcrumbs as result ?

Comment: (1) Please show the results that you want.  (2) Can you set up a db<>fiddle or something?

Comment: 1) I update the question with example

Comment: your sql statement references a table called `categories_category` which isn't mentioned anywhere else, is that a mistake? Minimal sample data would be useful, [here's a start](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2dddd1bcbb1d9ab654a51b836d77e1e2), can you fill that out?

Comment: @JackDouglas thanks, it was a mistake I updated in dbfiddle; in my query ordering by depth I have a path from the top category to the last child. The problem appear when I need to pass multiple paths; So I thought to use an array of array with json elements to group them;

Comment: If you have an updated db<>fiddle, you need to share the link with us, each fiddle  iteration has a unique link.

Comment: @JackDouglas done, I thought I'm updating over your start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html), [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html) and ordered [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select
     c.id,
     json_agg(
         json_build_object('name',c2.name,'slug',c2.slug)
         order by p.depth
     )
from categories as c
    inner join lateral unnest(c.path) with ordinality as p(id, depth) on true
    inner join categories as c2 on
        c2.id = p.id
where
    exists (
        select *
        from item_categories as tt
        where
            tt.item_id = 1 and
            tt.category_id = c.id
    )
group by
    c.id
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a5b1a2ccf318b94b8da0e34740316cf5)

Or you can use `depth` column from you table if you want:

```
select
     c.id,
     json_agg(
         json_build_object('name',c2.name,'slug',c2.slug)
         order by c2.depth
     )
from categories as c
    inner join categories as c2 on
        c2.id = any(c.path)
where
    exists (
        select *
        from item_categories as tt
        where
            tt.item_id = 1 and
            tt.category_id = c.id
    )
group by
    c.id
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2d4264f4b1c6c0347c2d69a44f189573)

What I don't like about [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) is that you have to name your columns explicitly doing double work, so I've tried to use[`to_json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) instead. It works, but honestly, I'm not that familiar with this syntax when alias of the table is passed to the function as an argument (see [`Using Composite Types in Queries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)) and could not make it work without [`lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-table-expressions.html) join:

```
select
     c.id,
     json_agg(to_json(d) order by c2.depth)
from categories as c
    inner join categories as c2 on
        c2.id = any(c.path)
    cross join lateral (select c.name, c.slug) as d
where
    exists (
        select *
        from item_categories as tt
        where
            tt.item_id = 1 and
            tt.category_id = c.id
    )
group by
    c.id
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6cb00b6c9321acdc7d0c58dc22038222)